# Correct alignment of multiple-line inequality

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations

I want to display a set of inequalities to look like the code below

```
  this is the lower bound
≤ this is the thing to be bounded
≤ this is the upper bound
```

My attempt to do this is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &\phantom{\leq} \text{this is the lower bound} \\
  & \leq \text{this is the thing to be bounded} \\
  & \leq \text{this is the upper bound}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, in the output, the first line is not quite aligned with the second and third lines, it starts a little bit earlier than desired.

[image: output of code above]

I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't the `\phantom` command do what I think it is supposed to?
2. How do I get the desired output?

Comment: As I understand it, the alignment in the amsmath `align` (and related) environments is designed such that if you substitute `\quad` for `\phantom{\leq}`, it should give the correct alignment.

Comment: @CharlesStaats No, you're wrong.

Comment: @egreg: I take it, then, that the example at the top of page 2 in ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf is a bad practice? Or is this only appropriate when the line begins with a binary operator?

Comment: @CharlesStaats That's “correct” just by chance (indeed the `+` is a bit at the left of the `b`).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get the proper alignment using the `\phantom` method, you need to write `\phantom{{}\leq{}}` rather than just `\phantom{\leq}`. Providing the empty "math atoms", `{}`, around `\leq` informs TeX that it should treat `\leq` as an object of type `mathrel` ("relational operator") rather than of type `mathord` ("ordinary math item").

You can also get the desired alignment without a `\phantom`. Just (i) place the alignment symbol (`&`) immediately before the `\text{...}` instructions on all three lines and (ii) insert `{}` between `\leq` and `&\text{...}` on lines 2 and 3.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &\phantom{{}\leq{}} \text{this is the lower bound} \\
  & \leq \text{this is the thing to be bounded} \\
  & \leq \text{this is the upper bound}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
         &\text{this is the lower bound} \\
  \leq{} &\text{this is the thing to be bounded} \\
  \leq{} &\text{this is the upper bound}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for informing me of the difference between `mathrel` and `mathord`. Why does the `\leq{}` example work with just a single pair of curly braces? I would have thought based on the first example that `{}\leq{}` would be required.

Comment: @ILiketoCode - If you look closely at the image I posted, you'll notice that the second group of three lines is placed ever so slightly to the *left* of the first group. (In both groups, of course, the spacing between the `\leq` symbols and the subsequent text is the same by design.) If you reran the MWE with `\leq{}` replaced by `{}\leq{}` in the second group, you'd find that the first and second groups were now lined up perfectly. Put differently, *not* putting a `{}` group before the `\leq` symbol does have an effect -- just not w.r.t. the spacing between `\leq` and the subsequent text.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `\mathrel{\phantom{\leq}}`. Or simply insert the required whitespace by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  & \mathrel{\phantom{\leq}} \text{this is the lower bound} \\
  & \leq \text{this is the thing to be bounded} \\
  & \leq \text{this is the upper bound}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  & \phantom{\leq} \; \; \text{this is the lower bound} \\
  & \leq \text{this is the thing to be bounded} \\
  & \leq \text{this is the upper bound}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please add image of resulted equation/use of your solution.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to add that surrounding, say, an equal sign with empty braces (i.e. `\phantom{{}={}}`) to get the right alignment does not work if the equal sign is followed by an operator. What does work, however, is using `\mathrel{\phantom{=}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &\phantom{{}={}} \sin(x) \\
  &= \sin(x)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \sin(x) \\
  &= \sin(x)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]